# how to describe return value type for own class using typing?

Tags: python, typing

Let's say that I have this code:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

class DEF:

  def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b

  @classmethod
  def from_dict(cls, source_dict: dict) -> DEF:
    return [cls(k, v) for k, v in source_dict.items()][0]

d = DEF.from_dict({"a": "b"})
```

And here is error happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 3, in <module>
    class DEF:
  File "example.py", line 10, in DEF
    def from_dict(cls, source_dict: dict) -> DEF:
NameError: name 'DEF' is not defined
```

I want to describe that `DEF.from_dict(...)` return self (own class) instance, but I can't set `-> DEF:` because of error above (`-> cls:` also raise same error).

Is it possible to annotate class for return value or method argument from inside same class?

Comment: your code doesn't really make sense. for instance, you're creating a class object with both key and value pair? also, the `[0]` means you're only return the first element of the list, so the better question I guess is why build the list in the first place.

Comment: so here I could suggest something like `cls(*next(iter(source_dict.items())))` as an alternative which preserves the same logic, after a fashion.

Comment: to resolve the `NameError`, I would suggest wrapping the `DEF` return type in single quotes.